# If you have an SSD and an HDD, how to use them efficiently?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, reparse-points

SSDs are better for reading data and HDDs are better for writing data.
SSDs are limited in size so I can only store a selected set of data on it.

- Should I install Windows on the SSD or on the HDD?
- Should I create junction points (soft/hard links) to move folders between the SSD and HDD?

  Eg. Temporary folders would better fit on the HDD,
    Program Files should be on the HDD but Games I play the most would fit better on the HDD.

  `SSD:\Windows\Temp` would be REPARSED to `HDD:\Temporary Files\Windows`
  `SSD:\Program Files` would be REPARSED to `HDD:\Programs`,
  `HDD:\Programs\A Good Game` to `SSD:\Program Files\A Good Game`

  Or will the REPARSES from the HDD to the SSD cause too much overhead?
- Are there any other tips regarding which data should be put on which drive?

Comment: It's not quite as straightforward as "SDD is better for reading data and a HDD is better for writing data". SSDs are excellent at *random* writes, and most SSDs are good at *sequential* writes. But the downside is that an SSD has a limited number of writes in its lifetime.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's because of the downside I don't want to write to it unless needed...

Comment: We've made a blog post about [Maximizing the lifetime of your SSD](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows, and games should be on your SSD.  Temp files on the HDD.  There are many other tips.. I would suggest doing some [research](http://lifehacker.com/5586733/how-to-take-full-advantage-of-your-solid+state-drive)